# Como Trocar consulta Arrays por consulta Selects no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Não estou sabendo como trocar arrays por consulta no sql, nesse código a baixo tem um array com registros gostaria de saber como se troca o array `$tabela_modelo` por um select no MySQL usando as mesmas colunas do array:

```
function get_marcas() {

// Aqui criamos um array bidimensional, que poderá vi do banco de
// dados da mesma forma
// basta você fazer um select * from tabela_marca -> a tabela_marca 
// deve conter: id_marca, ds_marca


$marcas = array(
        array('id_marca' => 11, 'ds_marca' => 'JW'),
        array('id_marca' => 1, 'ds_marca' => 'Transfer'),

        );
return $marcas;
}

function get_modelos($id_marca) {



// select * from tabela_modelo where id_marca = $id_marca 
// 



$tabela_modelo = array(
array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 1, 'ds_modelo' => 'Vectra'),
array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 2, 'ds_modelo' => 'Corsa'),
array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 3, 'ds_modelo' => 'Meriva'),
array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 4, 'ds_modelo' => 'Uno'),
array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 5, 'ds_modelo' => 'Tempra'),
array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 6, 'ds_modelo' => 'Pálio'),
array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 7, 'ds_modelo' => 'Ranger'),
array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 8, 'ds_modelo' => 'Eco'),
array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 9, 'ds_modelo' => 'Fiesta')
);

$modelo = array();
$cont = 0;
for($i=0; $i < count($tabela_modelo); $i++) {
    if($tabela_modelo[$i]['id_marca'] == $id_marca) {
        $modelo[$cont]['id_marca']= $tabela_modelo[$i]['id_marca'];
        $modelo[$cont]['ds_modelo'] = $tabela_modelo[$i]['ds_modelo'];
        $cont++;
    }
}
return $modelo;

}

 switch ($_POST['acao']) {
 case "exibeModeloSelect":
    $txt =  '<select name="id_motorista">';
    $txt .= '<option value="">Selecione o Motorista</option>';

    foreach(get_modelos($_POST['id_marca']) as $modelo) {
        $txt .= '<option value="'.$modelo['id_modelo'].'">' .   
  $modelo['ds_modelo'] . '</option>';   
    }

    $txt .= "</select>";

    echo $txt;
  break;
  }
```

Comment: vc deve armazenar esses dados em banco de dados. MySQL, SQLite, PostGre, SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, etc..

Comment: isso eu ja tenho armazenado. queria saber como passar a consulta para o mysql

Comment: Está usando o PDO ou MySQLi?

Comment: Por enquanto em mysql, mesmo apesar de saber que ja esta em desuso...

Comment: eu não entendi o problema, um `while` simples resolve, dentro dele, faça a atribuição, `$tabela_modelo[] = $row;`

Comment: Então ja tentei fazer e não funcionou   ... coloquei aqui como fiz a consulta  http://jsfiddle.net/cz4ph2w2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo exemplo mostrado, acredito que basta fazer a atribuição no array e retorna-lo no final da função, dessa forma:

`ctype_digit()` verifica se `$id_marca` é número inteiro caso contrario retorna um array vazio e `sprintf()` força a formatação da sql, se `%d` para inteiros.

```
function get_marcas() {
   $conexao = get_conexao();
   $sql = "select * from tabela_marca";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die(mysql_error($conexao));

   $marcas = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $marcas[] = $row;
   }
   return $marcas;
}

function get_modelos($id_marca) {
   if(!ctype_digit($id_marca)) return array();

   $conexao = get_conexao();

   $sql = sprintf("select * from tabela_modelo where id_marca = %d", $id_marca);
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die(mysql_error($conexao));

   $modelos = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $modelos[] = $row;
   }
   return $modelos;
}
```

[Manual - sprinf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

[Manual - ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo que eu queria.... só uma coisa...  quando o segundo select o "where id_marca = $id_marca  não encontra um 'id' ele da esse erro "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in"...  voce saberia como ocultar esse erro?

Comment: Não pode ocultar, precisa tratar ele.

Comment: @FabioHenrique, alterei a resposta veja se atende agora.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim

```
$tabela_modelos = array();
$tabela_modelos[] = array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 1, 'ds_modelo' => 'Vectra');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 2, 'ds_modelo' => 'Corsa');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 1, 'id_modelo' => 3, 'ds_modelo' => 'Meriva');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 4, 'ds_modelo' => 'Uno');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 5, 'ds_modelo' => 'Tempra');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 2, 'id_modelo' => 6, 'ds_modelo' => 'Pálio');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 7, 'ds_modelo' => 'Ranger');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 8, 'ds_modelo' => 'Eco');
$tabela_modelos[] =array('id_marca' => 3, 'id_modelo' => 9, 'ds_modelo' => 'Fiesta');

$cadastros = 0;

foreach($tabela_modelos as $tabela_modelo){
$id_marca = $tabela_modelo['id_marca'];
$id_modelo = $tabela_modelo['id_modelo'];
$ds_modelo = $tabela_modelo['ds_modelo'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO1 = "'.$id_marca.'"' ';

if(mysql_query($sql)){
$cadastrados++
}
}
```

Comment: Ola Amigo desculpa a minha iguinorancia.. mais não entendi oque vc fez

Comment: Você não quer fazer uma consulta com cara array do $tabela_modelos?? então eu estou fazendo o foreach para percorrer o array e inserir nas variáveis e em seguida faço a consulta passando a variável, essa consulta foi só um exemplo de como concatenar a variável na consulta

Comment: Não... eu quero fazer uma consulta no banco de dados.